# Can't get Mach-O text segment size in iOS executable

Tags: ios, executable, reverse-engineering, segment, mach-o

I'm trying to get .text segment size of Mach-O executable of my iOS app.

```
size_t size_of_image(struct mach_header *header) {
size_t sz = sizeof(*header); // Size of the header
sz += header->sizeofcmds;    // Size of the load commands

struct load_command *lc = (struct load_command *) (header + 1);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < header->ncmds; i++) {
    if (lc->cmd == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
        sz += ((struct segment_command *) lc)->vmsize; // Size of segments
    }
    lc = (struct load_command *) ((char *) lc + lc->cmdsize);
}
return sz;
}
```

and i call this function from main

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
const struct mach_header * header;
Dl_info dlinfo;
//
if (dladdr(main, &dlinfo) == 0 || dlinfo.dli_fbase == NULL)
    return 0; // Can't find symbol for main
//
header = dlinfo.dli_fbase;  // Pointer on the Mach-O header
size_of_image(header);
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Problem is **lc->cmd** is always 0, and i never get **LC_SEGMENT_64** command.

I've tried LC_SEGMENT - same result

Running iOS 12 on iPhone 6.
I need to get the .text segment of the executable for reverse - engineering protection functions.

It seems my ** mach_header *header** is wrongly field by **dladdr** function.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Hello Andrew, did you manage to solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: see answer below. it worked for me @AgustinPazos

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is in `struct mach_header *header`.
Replace it with `struct mach_header_64 *header` instead.
Keep using `LC_SEGMENT_64` for modern binaries.